# Printing coloured text in emacs mini-buffer and *Messages* buffer

Tags: colors, message

I want to print coloured text in the minibuffer and in the *Messages*.  Can this be done and how?

Comment: Please do not post the same question to both StackOverflow and emacs.SE. Please delete one and keep the other. (And please consider using the same user name for both sites.) Thx.

Answer (score 0):

`message` shows message strings with whatever properties you've given them. The function for adding text properties to a string is `propertize`.

See `C-h f propertize` and the Elisp manual, node [Changing Properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Properties.html).

```lisp
(message "%s" (propertize "My message" 'face 'highlight))
```

Or:

```lisp
(message "My %s" (propertize "message" 'face 'highlight))
```

Comment: `(message "%s" (propertize "Counting bracketing marks " 'face 'highlight))` did not colour the string.  How con I pass a hex-code instead.

Comment: Yes, it does. How are you evaluating it? Select it and use `eval-region`. Or put it in a function and call the function. If you still don't see highlighting in the message then try with `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Comment: I want to put it in a function and call the message that will display in colour in the mini-buffer and in the `*Messages*` buffer.

Comment: I have emacs use bold, so that highlight would not show any difference in how text is displayed.

Comment: You asked about function `message`, which shows text in the echo area. Buffer `*Messages*` doesn't display the message; instead, the string is printed there. Printing doesn't show text properties. As for "that highlight": use any face you want, instead of face `highlight`. You don't say what "I have emacs use bold" means. But if you're doing something that inhibits showing faces, well then, you won't see them, will you?

Comment: This is what I am using `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :weight 'bold)`.  I do not know details, but thought `message` prints to both the minibuffer and in the *Messages* buffer.  Can one print in colour in the mini-buffer and in the `*Messages*` buffer?  I am not aware of using anything that inhibits showing faces.

Comment: The problem with predefined faces is that one is most times unaware of the colours being used.  As I adhere to enhanced contrast standard AAA, they are almost never appropriate for me to use.

Comment: You don't have to use predefined faces. The point of the answer is (1) `message` does show propertized text and (2) you can use `propertize` to propertize a string. You can give it any text properties you like.

Comment: Ok, but how can I colour the text with a known hex-code?

Comment: Please don't keep extending questions, if you want help. Ask another question. In this case, your additional question has nothing per se to do with `message` and the echo area.

Comment: What is a "known hex-code"?